# Passing an Angular 2 component an @input through typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, input, angular-material

I have a component basically looking like

```
export class MyComponent{
  @Input() inp: string;
}
```

I have another component which uses Material's dialogue box as follows:

```
export class MyParentComponent{
  openDialog(): void {
     let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyComponent);
}
```

I wonder in what way I can transfer an @input argument to MyComponent.
The only solution I can think of is wraping MyComponent with another component that sends it an input argument through html, and using this new component as the parameter of 'open'.
Is there any other good solution where I don't have to create another component?

Comment: Have you checked the docs, where you can pass data to your component. Like in this sample from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)  where injecting the data in the constructor  : https://stackblitz.com/angular/pyovoknknjq?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts or am I misunderstanding your question? :)

Comment: The angular material documentation explains it pretty straight forward: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

The @Input is for template data binding only.

Comment: You are right, I missed the part where it described the 'data' property. Thanks

Comment: data property can be used. But what if the MyComponent prefer to not be modified because it's used elsewhere. And it's still looking for inp.